# Why does git-rebase encounter conflicts when upstream is already reachable?

Tags: git-rebase

I have a git branch "dev".  Branch "master" is reachable from dev.  While on branch "dev", if I type "git log master..dev --pretty=oneline" it clearly shows that master is reachable (104 commits earlier).  But if I type "git rebase master", it will stop with conflicts.  Why is that?  Shouldn't rebase have nothing to do in this case, since dev is already based on master?

The reason I am asking this is because I really want to do an interactive rebase with squashes and rewords to clean up a lengthy history.  But I am put off by having to resolve all the conflicts that should have already been resolved once I start the rebase.

The following are some related questions that I've already looked at:

- [Why does git-rebase give me merge conflicts when all I'm doing is squashing commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133449/why-does-git-rebase-give-me-merge-conflicts-when-all-im-doing-is-squashing-commit)
  [Conflicts with `git rebase`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465870/conflicts-with-git-rebase)

Comment: I think I see the problem now.  In branch dev's history.  There are many merges.  Master is only one of them.  So of course, when I want to rebase with master upstream, there are conflicts.  I'll just merge with master again w/ --strategy "ours" (I'm the only programmer - so no one else is affected by anything I do).

Answer (score 1):

`git rebase master` rebases your branch to be based off the *latest* commit in `master`.  If you want to base it off something earlier, you need to specify the exact commit, i.e.

```
git rebase `git merge-base master HEAD`
```

Answer (score 0):

### rebase != merge

If you just want to fast forward, use

```
git pull --ff-only ...
git merge --ff-only ...
```

If you want to 'automatically rebase/fastforward' depending on the current context and relationship of your branches, I suppose this would work:

```
git pull --rebase ...
```

You may want to read the man page on what it does, precisely

- http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/11/pull-with-rebase.html
- http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to merge from the repository.  I just want to clean up the history of my dev branch.